# Postgresql or other database: How to autosort rows and store position dynamically and efficiently?

Tags: database, postgresql, sorting

In my current schema, I have the scores of users in a mini-game (that not necessarily everyone is playing) with multiple types of scores.  For sake of argument, let's say the two scores are `hits` and `accuracy`.

I need to keep a scoreboard and ranking of all of my users (2.8 mil) who are currently playing this game (only 248k).  I know already anyone with `hits = 0` is not considered a player.

So let's say a player somewhere in the middle gets their 200th hit, getting an accuracy increase from .58 to .6, displacing other users who currently have 199 hits and accuracy between .58 and .6.  I want to store every ranking change dynamically and efficiently in each row in any method possible.  Essentially giving me the ability to run the following query:

`SELECT hit_ranking, accuracy_ranking FROM score WHERE user_id=100;`

I have tried or explored the following approaches:

1. Trigger on update to update all rows' ranking (this idea was deemed to be far too computationally expensive at 1/10 of our current userbase)
2. Cron job to sort all records in python and update them in the database incrementally (this took ~40 minutes with 60k users, and will not result in a good user experience)
3. Calculate each user's ranking on performing an action by storing a job in SQS (queueing service) and calculating ranking for that user

We have 3 running right now which worked at a smaller scale, but as the dataset grows it can take some time to calculate each ranking, and a lack of action on the user's end means they're never updated.

If postgresql or another database can store this data sorted dynamically (similar to the concept of a sorted heap), it would be a huge help.  I am willing to make this database its own instance as this mini-game is considered to be one of our growing features.

Comment: You could calculate the rank "on the fly" using `rank()` over `dense_rank()` - applying that to just 250k rows shouldn't take too long.

Comment: Well, saving each of those records in the backend, while still accounting for "new" users is not really scalable.  Even now it requires a rewrite on every record on the table

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [CREATE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) syntax in Postgres, namely the bit where you can combine multiple columns as an expression, and sort them descending.

So, something like

```
CREATE INDEX index_hitrank ON scoreboard (hits DESC);
CREATE INDEX index_accuracyrank ON scoreboard (accuracy DESC);
```

Even simple maths is possible

```
CREATE INDEX index_bothrank ON scoreboard (hits + accuracy DESC);
```

`SELECT * from scoreboard order by hits DESC` should then be nice and fast :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.  While I do, will this solution give me the current rank for one entry out of an entire table?  i.e. Will I be able to get `SELECT * FROM score WHERE user_id=100`?

Comment: Actually wait what am I saying, it's an index on sorting.  While that's going to be useful for other purposes, for getting the rank of a single record I don't think this will help out.  Querying the entire table isn't exactly efficient.

Comment: Try it out. Without more concrete details around the exact table definitions and DDL, it's hard to recommend something.

Comment: Ignore the above comment - An additional index on `user_id` would solve for your problem :)

Comment: It actually helped out a lot with another issue that came up yesterday, hence an upvote.  But it won't help store the user's ranking.  I already do have a query running that finds the user's rank using a few filters and an order by, but even though it's indexed, for a high-traffic backend it's pretty slow.

Comment: Show us the table DDL and the specific query, and we can optimise it. You can then use those learnings for this project.